# how to debug bazel skylark script step by step with a debugger

Tags: bazel

I am trying to compile my [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) code with [Bazel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazel_(software)). I want to dig deeply into what happened behind the surface. Is there any debugger tool(like a [GDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) debugger) that can be used to debug the [Google Bazel Skylark](https://bazel.build/rules/language) code, I want to track the Bazel Skylark script execution step by step and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@László is correct though there has been some work done on this which you might be able to utilize.

See this thread from bazel-dev: [[Design doc] Debugging Protocol for Skylark and Bazel Integration](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/bazel-dev/Wg6QN59FJ80/pvSwigfeCAAJ)

Comment: This is useful for me. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you’re able to make any headway with it I suggest you accept this answer to let others know it’s an option. Good luck!

Comment: @JiewenZheng: Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) whichever answer has most helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there's no Skylark debugger yet.

Though it's not a debugger, you can use [`print`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#print) to print debug messages.

Answer (score 3):

Use VSCode with [the Bazel plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BazelBuild.vscode-bazel).
In the future, I hope other IDEs/tools will support the protocol too.

Comment: Could you share a detailed tutorial about how to build and step debug Bazel script. Thanks.

Comment: There are some explanations here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/vscode-bazel#using-the-starlark-debugger
If it's unclear or doesn't work for you, can you please file an issue on GitHub?